# Create your own Android virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, android

Is there a way to create a virtual machine based on an actual device, if so, how would someone do it?

Note: The emulator should have the same ROM as the device.

Comment: No. The system partition and bootloader might be locked and encrypted so no one can read them out. Moreover virtual machine runs a computer with the same architecture. To run another architecture you have to use an **emulator**. And how can you match the phone's spec in an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for and maybe you already know but Android Studio let's you select various devices for virtual emulation and if you really want you can create your own hardware profiles.

Comment: Yes I know about that, but I also want to have the same firmware on the emulator as my device.

Comment: @Gerard Balaoro you can pick the OS you want to run on the emulated device in Android studio

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, ,ost tools for virtualization of Android - Virtualbox + Vmware support only x86 Android some ROM is basically PC. 
  Only tool which is capable to simulate different instruction set and convert it into other instruction set is QEMU/Bochs, but is slow and ROM is ARM like, but configuration is pretty limited. So maybe in some far future we would have something like that.

Now best way is physical device and remote control +some scripting for automated testing.